# log4c link error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, log4c

Been trying to use log4c in an eclipse IDE. No matter what I try, I can't seem to resolve the __log4c_category_vlog reference in my link.

I can see __log4c_category_vlog via an objdump of the liblog4c.a file, I've tried modifying some of the code in the category.c/category.h files before I do the make/make install, all to no avail.  I've set my linker to point to the proper lib64 folder, added proper include etc in Eclipse.

The sample programs that come with log4c compile/link/run ok, so I must be missing something obvious.  Any help/heads up appreciated!

- log4c version:1.2.4
- Eclipse version:luna
- Linux: Opensuse 13.2
- gcc version: 4.8.3 20140627

***/home/david/build3/include/log4c/category.h:359: undefined reference to `__log4c_category_vlog'
makefile:30: recipe for target 'testLog4c' failed
./src/testLog4c.o: In function`log4c_category_log':***